# R Shiny: Print input from a selectInput function created dynamically from prior inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am struggling to print the output of various `selectInput` options on my 'Example_2' tab. These fields themselves have been created within the server based on prior inputs from 'Example_1' tab.

Please see below:

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
rm(list = ls())

ui <-  navbarPage('Example',id = "inTabset",
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_1", value = "Example_1",
                           fluidPage(
                               tags$b( h4("Example_1", align = "left")),
                             theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                             fluidRow(
                               column(6,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label ="", 
                                                           choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                                                           selected = c(1,4,7)) )
                              ),
                             br()
                           ),
                           hr(),
                           verbatimTextOutput("example1")
                  ),
                  
               tabPanel(title = "Example_2", value = "Example_2", 
                                         fluidPage( 
                                           tags$b( h4("Example_2", align = "left")),
                                           br(),
                                           fluidRow(   
                                             column(4, uiOutput("VarsInput")),
                                           fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")),
                                           br(),
                                           hr())    
                                )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example1 = renderPrint(input$checkGroup)
  ### output$example2 = ????
  ### i.e what data (a,b,c,d,e or f) has been chosen from the selectInput below? 
  
  
  K <- reactive({
    length(input$checkGroup)
  })
  
  output$VarsInput <- renderUI({
    NoV = K()
    C = sapply(1:(ceiling(NoV)), function(i){paste0(input$checkGroup[i])})
    
    output = tagList()
    for(i in seq_along(1:ceiling(NoV))){
      output[[i]] = tagList()
      output[[i]][[1]] = selectInput(C[i], C[i], c("",c("a","b","c","d","e","f")))
      }
    output
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ui` I added `verbatimTextOutput` for your `example2`.

When dynamically creating outputs, I believe you just need `output[[i]]` in your for loop.

For name of these `selectInput` widgets, added "item" instead of just having the id be a number.

Then, you can access the selected values for these inputs through `input[[paste0("item", i)]]` where `i` is matched to your checkboxes.

**Edit (12/27/20)** Based on comment, with varying checkboxes and inputs, you will want to store both the input name (or index) and choice. So, you could make a `reactive` data frame to store these, instead of just storing the value selected. Also, you need to check if the dynamically created input exists (or `is.null`) before storing the value. Additionally, when you create your new dynamic inputs, you can check with the index to provide an accurate default/selected value. See if this works for you.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)

ui <-  navbarPage('Example',id = "inTabset",
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_1", value = "Example_1",
                           fluidPage(
                             tags$b( h4("Example_1", align = "left")),
                             theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                             fluidRow(
                               column(6,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label ="", 
                                                           choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                                                           selected = c(1,4,7)) )
                             ),
                             br()
                           ),
                           hr(),
                           verbatimTextOutput("example1")
                  ),
                  
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_2", value = "Example_2", 
                           fluidPage( 
                             tags$b( h4("Example_2", align = "left")),
                             br(),
                             fluidRow(   
                               column(4, uiOutput("VarsInput")),
                               fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")),
                               br(),
                               hr(),
                               verbatimTextOutput("example2"))    
                           )
                  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  observe({
    rv$df <- data.frame(
      index = as.numeric(),
      choice = as.character()
    )
    for (i in input$checkGroup) {
      the_item <- input[[paste0("item", i)]]
      rv$df <- isolate(rbind(rv$df, data.frame(index = i, choice = ifelse(is.null(the_item), "", the_item))))
    }
  })
  
  output$example1 = renderPrint(input$checkGroup)
  
  output$example2 <- renderPrint(
    for (i in input$checkGroup) {
      print(input[[paste0("item", i)]])
    }
  )
  
  K <- reactive({
    length(input$checkGroup)
  })
  
  output$VarsInput <- renderUI({
    NoV = K()
    C = sapply(1:(ceiling(NoV)), function(i){paste0(input$checkGroup[i])})
    output = tagList()
    for(i in seq_along(1:ceiling(NoV))){
      output[[i]] = tagList()
      output[[i]] = selectInput(paste0("item", C[i]), C[i], c("",c("a","b","c","d","e","f")), 
                                selected = isolate(rv$df$choice[rv$df$index == C[i]]))
    }
    output
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. In addition to this, would it be possible to have the selected inputs in example 2 persist even if one were to alter example 1. For example, if I select 'a' for ```selectInput``` 1, then go back and change the `checkInputs` (but still retain number 1), number 1 now loses its selection of 'a'. Would there be a way to retain this selection?

Comment: @Graham See edited answer for one approach. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Thanks very much, @Ben.

Comment: I'm just working through this again, @Ben. If, for example, I select 'a' for ```selectInput``` 4, but then go back to check 3 also, 'a' now drops back to  ```selectInput``` 3. Would there be a way to counteract this? Many thanks

Comment: @Graham Please see edited answer, and let me know if this works for you.